# Manipulate cmd ping color based on time

Tags: windows, cmd, ping

My internet is not always working properly and I'd like to check the quality based on the cmd windows tool. I believe it's a task simple enough for it to handle.
I've begun by making a shortcut so I can have easy access to the command:

```
    C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE 8.8.8.8 -t
```

Now I was trying to transform the cmd ping command into a visually responsive one based on the output. I'd like to make the color change according to the time response.
After looking and not finding anything related, I believe it's either impossible or no one has ever tried.

Thank you very much :)
PD: (In case there was anything unclear just ask and I'll gladly answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Magoo's post, I wrote this little batch program.
It asks for the target, the number of requests to make, the max time allowed and the time between requests and then prints in red if the request is over the time max, otherwise it sums the number of requests. It includes timestamp to be more accurate.

Copy and paste in a text file and name it with extension ".bat" (But don't name it "ping.bat" otherwise the program will enter in an infinite loop).

```
REM CMD PING TOOL
REM By Daweb
REM https://stackoverflow.com/users/3779294/daweb    

@ECHO OFF

REM Needed for Line colored
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a IN ('"PROMPT #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  SET "DEL=%%a"
)
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"


ECHO *****************
ECHO * CMD PING TOOL *
ECHO *****************

REM Start
:start

ECHO.
ECHO Set yours values

REM SET Target
SET /p hostInput=" - Target (ip or hostname): "
If "%hostInput%"=="" ECHO.&GOTO start

REM SET loops
SET /p loopsInput=" - Requests number: "
SET /a loops=loopsInput

REM SET time limit
SET /p maxmsInput=" - Maximum Time Limit (ms): "
SET /a maxms=maxmsInput

REM Value used for sleep between loops
SET /p sleepInput=" - Delay between requests (s): "
SET /a sleepDelay=sleepInput+1

REM Variables
SET displayText=""
SET /a countRequestsOk=0
SET /a countRequestsKo=0
SET /a totalRequests=0
SET /a maxTime=0

ECHO.
ECHO START at %TIME% [target: %hostInput%, requests: %loops%, time limit: %maxms% ms, delay: %sleepInput% s]
ECHO.


REM Loop
:loop

REM Set time
FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:" %%a IN ("%TIME%") DO (SET mytime=%%ah%%bm%%cs)

REM Get ping value
FOR /f "tokens=3delims==" %%a IN ('PING -n 1 %hostInput%') DO FOR /f "delims=m" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (

    SET /a timems=%%b
    SET /a totalRequests+=1

    REM Check result
    IF !timems! GTR %maxms% ( GOTO failed ) ELSE (  GOTO success )

)


REM Request success
:success
SET /a countRequestsOk+=1
IF !timems! GTR !maxTime! ( SET /a maxTime=timems )
<nul set /P "=!countRequestsOk! requests [Max !maxTime! ms]!CR!"

GOTO next


REM Request failed
:failed
IF !countRequestsOk! GTR 0 ECHO.

SET /a countRequestsOk=0
SET /a countRequestsKo+=1

SET displayText=" %mytime% - !timems!ms"
CALL :ColorText 0c !displayText!

GOTO next


REM Next loop
:next

REM Sleep a little bit
IF %sleepDelay% GTR 1 ( ping -n %sleepDelay% localhost > nul )

REM Check continue
SET /a loops-=1
IF %loops% gtr 0 GOTO loop


REM Display result
IF !countRequestsOk! GTR 0 ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO STOP at %TIME%
ECHO.

if !countRequestsKo! GTR 0 (
    SET displayText="FAILED - !countRequestsKo! requests over %maxms% ms on !totalRequests! requests in total"
    CALL :ColorText 0c !displayText!
) ELSE (
    SET displayText="SUCCESS - No request over %maxms% ms on !totalRequests! requests in total"
    CALL :ColorText 02 !displayText!
)


REM Ask if restart
ECHO.&ECHO *********************
SET /p restartInput="Do it again ? (Y/N): "
If "%restartInput%"=="" ECHO *********************&GOTO start
If /I "%restartInput%"=="y" ECHO *********************&GOTO start
If /I "%restartInput%"=="n" ECHO *********************&GOTO end


REM End
:end
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF


REM Line color
:ColorText
ECHO off
ECHO %DEL% > "%~2"
FINDSTR /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" NUL
DEL "%~2" > NUL 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This exactly what I was looking for!


Now that some time has passed, I have found some improvements that could be done, but since I have way more experience with programming I might give the a shot myself. Thanks again for the support and clear explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET loops=10
:loop
FOR /f "tokens=3delims==" %%a IN ('PING 8.8.8.8 -n 1') DO FOR /f "delims=m" %%b IN ("%%a") DO ECHO %%b&COLOR %%b&GOTO cchgd
:cchgd
PAUSE
SET /a loops-=1
IF %loops% gtr 0 GOTO loop
COLOR

GOTO :EOF
```

A simple demonstration - repeats the `ping` 10 times, changing colours depending on the response. Manipulate to do as you wish...

Comment: I'm not used at all with that notation... Could you give me a reference where to learn how to edit each variable or in case that's too tedious I'd appreciate having a functional code.
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I know what the desired output should be, but this will output GREEN text for response times 0-39 ms, YELLOW for 40-79 ms, and RED for 80+ ms.

Run this from a cmd.exe prompt using the following command or put it into a .bat file script. Change the directory to the location where the Get-PingColor.ps1 file is landed.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%USERPROFILE%\bin\Get-PingColor.ps1"
```

=== Get-PingColor.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$ComputerNames

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [int]$Count = 4

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [int]$SpeedMinimumSlow = 80

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [int]$SpeedMinimumMedium = 40
)
foreach ($ComputerName in $ComputerNames) {
    $Pings = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count $Count
    $Average = ($Pings | Measure-Object -Property responsetime -Average).Average
    $ForegroundColor = 'Green'
    if ($Average -ge $SpeedMinimumSlow) { $ForegroundColor = 'Red'}
    else { if ($Average -ge $SpeedMinimumMedium) { $ForegroundColor = 'Yellow' }}

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor $ForegroundColor -BackgroundColor 'Black' "$ComputerName $Average ms"
}
```

=== Execution examples

I am loathe to put images into a post, but I do not see a way to produce color on SO.
[image: localhost example]
[image]